# Phaser-3: Is there a way to move an image from one location to another while the program is running and so it is visible doing so?

Tags: javascript, image, phaser-framework

i would like to create a battle system for an rpg game ,where an opening animation plays showing the battling characters move from the side of the screen to a location on the screen. Current code, assets and current running view provided below;

```html
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>battle</title>
    <script src="phaser.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript">
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 1900,
    height: 900,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 0},
            debug: false
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update,
        
        }
    };
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload(){ 
    this.load.image("background","assets/battle background.png");
    this.load.image("hydroBot","assets/water hydrant.png");
    
};
function create(){
    const battle = this.add.image(0,0,"background").setOrigin(0,0);
    const bot= this.add.image(1000,200,"hydroBot");
    bot.setScale(5);
   
    
};
function update(){

};

</script>
</body>
```

[water_hydrant/hydrobot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDLzc.png)

[the battle background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpUAk.png)

[the current view when running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RnNb.png)

much appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check for tween. You can move the image by using it.